# Strategy when selecting sum of dice roll

Tags: probability, expected-value

I was wondering about the following question.
Suppose you roll a 6-sided and a 10-sided die. You will receive exactly the sum of the numbers on the dice only if you guess the sum correctly. What number do you guess?

Well, it appears to me that one ought to choose 11 for the simple reason that the expected value is greatest in this case.
Overall, the outcomes with the biggest probability are 8, 9, 10 and 11; each with probability 6/60.
The outcome is greatest for 11, as 11*6/60 is the biggest number out of all the possible rewards given to the player.

Is this thinking correct?

Much obliged for any help I receive.

Comment: This is correct, though for completeness you should discuss the case of $12$ as well and explain why it should be decreasing from that point on.  If you aren't against the use of computers, this can be verified trivially by looking at the coefficients of $x\cdot \frac{d}{dx}\left[(x+x^2+x^3+\dots+x^6)(x+x^2+\dots+x^{10})\right]$ and finding which coefficient in the expansion is greatest which you will see does indeed correspond to the $x^{11}$ term.

Comment: Yup, you just want to maximize the expectation. I won't verify that $11$ is correct but that seems reasonable.

Comment: It won't affect the final answer, but you overlooked that 7 is just as likely.

Comment: As indicated by the comment of @JMoravitz, you should probably discuss $~\displaystyle \frac{12}{11} ~\text{versus}~ \frac{6}{5},~$ $~\displaystyle \frac{13}{11} ~\text{versus}~ \frac{6}{4},~$ $~\displaystyle \frac{14}{11} ~\text{versus}~ \frac{6}{3},~ \cdots.$